# How to find character bigrams and trigrams?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, classification, nltk

**Problem:**

Finding the bigrams, trigrams and bigram_score of a domain_name.I have a dataset and I want to differentiate them whether they are dga domains or not using some simple classification.So i wanted to use bigrams, trigrams and entropy to start with.

**What I tried:**

```
from nltk import ngrams
sentence = 'some big sentence'
n = 2
sixgrams = ngrams(sentence.split(), n)
for grams in sixgrams:
print grams
```

here i got bigrams of a sentence.But my intenstion is not this.

i want to convert

**Example domain: google.co.in**

```
bigrams

[‘$g’, ‘go’, ‘oo’, ‘og’, ‘gl’, ‘le’, ‘e$’, ‘$c’, ‘co’, ‘o$’, ‘$i’, ‘in’, ‘n$’]
trigrams

[‘$go’, ‘goo’, ‘oog’, ‘ogl’, ‘gle’, ‘le$’, ‘$co’, ‘co$’, ‘$in’, ‘in$’]
```

and then calculate the bigrams_score.From which i can use it to prediction module and analyze.

Can anyone help me in getting an idea of how to solve the problem?

Comment: Why does it not work with `sentence = 'google.co.in'`?

Comment: It returns empty set.I already tried.

Comment: You may want to add that in your question, right? (I must admit that I have no idea why it fails, then.)

Comment: I copied your code and for "here i got bigrams of a sentence", I get `('some', 'big') ('big', 'sentence')` instead, which are more 'bi-words' than bigrams. Perhaps `ngrams(..)` does *not* split your input into two-letter parts but in two *word* parts only. (Which, come to think of it, would explain why a single word phrase silently fails.) **Edit** Oh wait, similar questions on `ngrams(..)` also work with *words*, not with *letters*. Seems you are using the wrong package.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, ngrams
>>> s = "foo bar sentence"

# Word ngrams.
>>> list(ngrams(word_tokenize(s), 2))
[('foo', 'bar'), ('bar', 'sentence')]

# Character ngrams.
>>> list(ngrams(s, 2))
[('f', 'o'), ('o', 'o'), ('o', ' '), (' ', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('a', 'r'), ('r', ' '), (' ', 's'), ('s', 'e'), ('e', 'n'), ('n', 't'), ('t', 'e'), ('e', 'n'), ('n', 'c'), ('c', 'e')]
```

Comment: Perfect .. .Thanks.

Comment: BTW, `from nltk import everygrams; list(everygrams(s, 2, 3))`

Comment: @SaiKiran Would be good to accept this as an answer if it answered your question.